# Wait for visibility in python using selenium 3

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a website https://uptake.com/

When I click on the "Contact US" button it loads a popup in the form of additional  tags.

**NOTE: This is not a normal popup window**

I would like to access the submit button that appears in this.

But through normal methods such as just waiting  5 seconds after clicking I get an Exception: Element not visible.

Comment: Please add your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [selenium's expected conditions](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp). Find the element you want to wait for using your developer tools, and tell selenium to wait for it before grabbing the content.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually... Turned out that I had to **click a button twice** to make the popup appear. For some reason selenium fails to invoke the popup in one click. Very strange!!! My code works now. I wonder if it is a possible synchronization issue.